# Pandas sorting by value and then by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy.random as random

random.seed(12)

df = DataFrame (
    {
        "fac1" : ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"] ,
        "val" : random.choice(np.arange(0,20), 8, replace=False)
    }
)
df2 = df.set_index(["fac1"])
df2
```

[image]

What I want is to sort by `val` within each `fac1` group, to produce this:

[image]

I have combed the documentation and cannot find a straightforward way.  The best I could do was the following hack:

```
df3 = df2.reset_index()
df4 = df3.sort_values(["fac1","val"],ascending=[True,True],axis=0)
df5 = df4.set_index(["fac1"])
df5
# Produces the picture above
```

(I realize the above could benefit from multiple `inplace` options, just doing it this way to make intermediate products clear).

I did find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190633/python-pandas-sorting-by-multiindex-and-column), which uses grouping and a sorting function.  However the following code, adapted from that post, produced an incorrect result:

```
df2.groupby("fac1",axis=1).apply(lambda x : x.sort_values("val"))
```

(Output removed for space considerations)

Is there another way to approach this?

### Update: Solution

The accepted solution is:

```
df2.sort_values(by='val').sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

The sorting algorithm **must be `mergesort`** and it must be explicitly specified as it is not the default.  As [the `sort_index` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) points out, "mergesort is the only [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) algorithm." Here's another sample dataset that will not sort properly if you don't specify `mergesort` for `kind`:

```
random.seed(12)

len = 32 

df = DataFrame (
    {
        "fac1" : ["a" for i in range(int(len/2))] + ["b" for i in range(int(len/2))] ,
        "val" : random.choice(np.arange(0,100), len, replace=False)
    }
)
df2 = df.set_index(["fac1"])
df2.sort_values(by='val').sort_index()
```

(Am omitting all outputs for space consideration)

Comment: I've been trying to narrow down the point at which the failure occurs, and it's related to `len` - for everything else in the code equal the proposed solution works for len <= 16 and fails for larger values.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT: I looked into the documentation and the default sorting algorithm for sort_index is quicksort. This is NOT a "stable" algorithm, in that it does not preserve "the input order of equal elements in the sorted output" (from Wikipedia). However, sort_index gives you the option to choose "mergesort", which IS a stable sorting algorithm. So the fact that my original answer,

```
df2.sort_values(by='val').sort_index()
```

, worked, was simply happenstance. This code should work every time, since it uses a stable sorting algorithm:

```
df2.sort_values(by='val').sort_index(kind = 'mergesort')
```

Comment: I just came upon the same thing while you were writing that last edit.  Yup that's the answer.  That being said, I'm kinda surprised that `mergesort` isn't the default for `kind`.  Well I guess a case could be made either way.  Anyway I think this resolves it

Comment: Im also surprised, but I think that it can take much longer in a worst-case scenario.

Comment: Agreed - judging by the documentation, it all goes back to the underlying numpy `ndarray` implementation.  That library is really built for speed; at the same time, up at the pandas layer, my use case is a common one (I'm new to pandas but have done data science/stats for many years, mostly on SAS, where this is easy to do.)  I think the API could be improved by having a boolean `stable` parameter instead of algorithm choice - people would be more likely to notice it.  Anyway, now we know!  Thx again (and enjoy the bounty :-) ).

Comment: If to you as well as me it is necessary to sort at first on a column, and then on an index you should change the order of sorting! e.g `.sort_index().sort_values('A', kind='mergesort')`